# Segmentation when using node-oracle on ubuntu

Tags: oracle, node.js, node-oracle

I'm using node-oracle module with the following code (from the node-oracle documentation):

```
var oracle = require("oracle");

oracle.connect({ "hostname": "192.168.1.120/orcl", "user": "USER", "password": "PASS" }, function(err, connection) {
  if(err){ console.log("Connect err:" + err); }
  if(connection){ console.log("Connection:" + connection); }

  // selecting rows
connection.execute("SELECT nickname FROM users WHERE nickname = :1", ['luc'], function(err, results) {
  console.log("execution");
  console.log("RESULTS:" + results);
  console.log("Err:" + err);
});

connection.setAutoCommit(true);

connection.commit(function(err) {
  console.log("commiting");
  // transaction committed
});

connection.rollback(function(err) {
  console.log("rollback");
  // transaction rolledback
});

connection.close(); // call this when you are done with the connection
});
```

This gives me different error messages :

```
$ node test_node_oracle.js 
Connection:[object Connection]
rollback
commiting
execution
RESULTS:undefined
Err:Error: ORA-24324: service handle not initialized
```

Sometimes it also gives:

```
$ node test_node_oracle.js 
Connection:[object Connection]
Segmentation fault
```

or also:

```
$ node test_node_oracle.js 
Connection:[object Connection]
commiting
rollback
execution
RESULTS:undefined
Err:Error: ORA-32102: invalid OCI handle
```

sqlplus access works fine though:

$ sqlplus USER/PASS@192.168.1.120/orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Mon Mar 12 15:18:18 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
connection.close(); // call this when you are done with the connection
```

I believe this get's called too soon, because all statements are [non-blocking in node.js(event-loop)](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/10/understanding-the-event-loops-and-writing-great-code-for-node-js-part-1/). You should probably wrap it in proper callback(s) inside `commit` and `rollback`. You should also wrap all your code inside of `connection` callback

```
oracle.connect({ "hostname": "192.168.1.120/orcl", "user": "USER", "password": "PASS" }, function(err, connection) {
// wrap all your code inside of this.
}
```